# How to calculate the covariance of different tensors?

Tags: python, numpy, tensor

I am working with *tensors*. A tensor is a geometric object that maps in a multi-linear manner geometric vectors, scalars, and other tensors to a resulting tensor. More about tensors in [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor].

> I want to calculate the covariance of different tensors. I need the implementation in python.

I know how we can calculate the covariance of matrixes. But, there is no information about tensors.

I would like to know the result of the covariance of tensors.

**Update:**

I am trying to implement this article[https://www.dropbox.com/s/kunguyz1ousm885/Metric-Learning.pdf?dl=0].
In this article, the purpose is to learn metrics from different domains. In the optimization formula number 11 and page 5, W is said to be the covariance of tensors.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I only know the covariance of a pair of random variables, and how to estimate it from some observations (what you call the "covariance of matrices"). Can you explain what is the covariance of a tensor?

Comment: @BlackBear I am implementing an article for metric learning. From every binary classifier, we have weights which are tensors. In the article, it calculates the covariance of these tensors and put the result as an element in the optimization equation.

Comment: Can you put a link to the article? I have not heard of a tensor covariance. Maybe they call tensors multidimensional vectors? Like tensorflow?

Comment: @MihaiAndrei  I updated the question and uploaded the article.

Comment: @MasoudErfani thanks. This is quite complex. Try mathoverflow. I short on time now. At this point this is not about python but about understanding the article.

Comment: @MihaiAndrei Thank you. Sure, I kinda understood the article and I implemented some part of the equation. This part implementation was just left